# How to read a bulk number image files in R?

Tags: r, image, xgboost

I have more than 400 image files in my loacl directory.I want to read these images in r for passing it through XG boost algorithm..My two tries(codes) are  is given below

```
library("EBImage")
img <- readImage("/home/vishnu/Documents/XG_boost_R/Data_folder/*.jpg")
```

and

```
library(jpeg)
library(biOps)
myjpg <- readJpeg("/home/vishnu/Documents/XG_boost_R/Data_folder/*.jpg")
```

Comment: Do you know how to read *ONE* image file? Show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hard to guess what you want to do exactly, but one way to accomplish loading a lot of files and processing them is via a `for`-loop like this:

```
files <- list.files() #create a vector with file names


for(i in 1:length(files)){#loop over file names

  load(files[i]) #load .rda-file

#do some processing and save results

}
```

This structure is generalizable to other cases. Depending on what kind of files you want to load, you will have to replace `load(files[i])` with the appropriate command, for instance `load.image()` from the `imager` package.